# Webpack 4. ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: webpack4

Есть webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        main: ['./src/js/main.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [ 'script-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['env'] }
                }]
            },           
        ]
    },
    target: 'web'
};
```

В файле main.js добавил import $ from "jquery", потому что использую там jquery

```js
import $ from "jquery";
$(document).ready(function () {
...
});
```

Но при открытии браузера в консоли пишет ReferenceError: require is not defined. Может кто сталкивался с данной проблемой и подскажет что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем вы используете script-loader? 
Без него данной ошибки - нет.

Дело в том, что script-loader подключает скрипт в глобальном контексте. Т.е. он запишет всё содержимое *.js файлов как есть в переменную и далее выполнит eval над ним. Конечно в данном случаи никакие минификаторы и babel над ним ними не запускаются - от сюда ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Только начинаю разбираться в webpack, поэтому извините если задаю простые вопросы. Ошибка все таки есть ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. Потому что я убрал из html  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>. Мне нужно чтобы webpack сам нашел и заменил строки с jquery на нормальний код. Или это невозможно?

Comment: Т.к. вы явно импортируете модуль jquery из node_modules в main.js, то вам нет необходимости подключать script jquery в теле страницы.

Comment: Моя цель не просто добавить jquery(85 KB) перед моим main.js(25KB), а а как то заменить код написанный на jquery в main.js и таким образом не добавлять лишние 85 KB. Тем не менее первый вопрос был задан по другому и вы на него ответили. Спасибо за помощь